# In how many ways can I extend the basis of a vector space over a finite field?

Tags: vector-spaces, finite-fields

Suppose I've a finite field, say for convenience $\mathbb F_p$, and I take the two extensions $\mathbb F^{p^m}$ and $\mathbb F^{p^n}$ as vector spaces over it. If $m<n$ and $m|n$, in how many ways can I get a basis for $\mathbb F^{p^n}$ from a basis of $\mathbb F^{p^m}$? Is there any way to count this easily?

Comment: I think you can solve this by just using this fact: Given a linearly independent set of vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ in a vector space $V$, the set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n,v_{n+1}\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $v_{n+1} \not\in \textrm{Span}(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but I think you want to require $m \mid n$, as otherwise $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$.

Comment: Yes. I'm getting $\prod_{i=m}^{n-1}(p^n-p^i)$. Is that correct, or am I making a mistake?